# UI freezes when at the particular task and only when accessing from terminal machine

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, user-interface, stored-procedures

For some reason User Interface freezes for 7-12 seconds when double click to open a PolicyNumber to display details.
And its only happens when accessing the application from the terminal machine. 
From the local server it works fine.

Interesting thing is if I keep open the same PolicyNumber right after I just close it - then it works fine, but if I wait 2-3 minutes and try to open the same PolicyNumber - then it freezes for approx 10-12 seconds.

I used SQL Profiler to track what is going on but couldn't find anything suspicious. Plus it seems like all sql statements and SP's are completed - but the UI still "thinking".

[image]

What would that be? What else should I check?

Comment: Sounds like it takes a while to get the data, but if you request it again while it's still in the DB's cache it is returned faster. The first thing to do is to instrument the code so that you know precisely where it is spending time.

Comment: "Instrument the code" meaning keep using SQL Profiler and try to narrowing down the problem? Or maybe there are some other good ways to troubleshoot? Thanks

Comment: Use a timer in the code to measure intervals and log the results for analysis. It may be helpful to include other data in the log, e.g. policy number, ... . One of the challenges is to avoid changing the system to excess in the process of observing it, e.g. capturing the intervals between statements in a function using local variables, then writing the set to a local log file would change the behavior less than writing a time stamp for each statement to a file across a network.